# Extract xhtml styles to css?

Tags: java, css, jsf, xhtml

I'm about to update one of my old projects.
I was using mixed css files and inline style properties. A lot of `<h:form style="display:inline-block;" />` `<h:outputText style="text-size: 1.1em" />` and so on.

What is the best way to factor all these styling statements out into a css file? To having no more styling definitions in the xhtml pages.

Or is there already a tool capable of?

ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [tool](http://www.tinytool.net/96002/inline_css_extractor) that could help you. In any case you gonna have to check by yourself the generated style sheet if everything is correct, as errors can easily be created with this kind of tool.

Comment: that tool is neat and fits perfectly! tyvm

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether this will work correctly but here it is,

http://lab.xms.pl/css-generator/